# Mongoid - .limit(n) ignored

Tags: mongoid

The mongoid 7.0 `.limit(n)` seems to be partially ignored.

When querying data and limiting it's size, the `.limit(n)` works as expected just after making an array out of it or when iterating over the items. It's not ideal but ok.

But the bigger problem appears when using the limit in combination with update_all.

```
Model.where(foo: 'bar').limit(100).update_all(foo: 'baz')
```

In this case the limit is entirely ignored and the update updates all the documents without taking the limit into account.

Sure, you can always go one by one, but that's probably something you don't want to do on bigger data (thousands of documents at the time in our case).

The only workaround I could think of is to select the document ids. Make an array out of them, create a query that would search only for those id documents and update them together.

```
ids = Model.where(foo: 'bar').only('_id').limit(1000).to_a
Model.where(:_id.in => ids).update_all(foo: 'baz')
```

Is there any way to make the limit work without making an array of the data first?

Answer (score 0):

The update command [does not provide for arbitrary limiting of the number of updates performed](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/). You can update one document or all matching documents.